# Shopware Frontend 500 | SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '/' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, database, shopware, shopware6, http-status-code-500

I´m currently trying to move Shopware 6 to a new Hoster (root Server).
I copied the DB, set-up the server and the Webspace and I´m able to log in into the Backend.
But when I´m in the frontend I get a 500 error, which is why I activated Shopware Debug.

**There I got the following error:**
*Could not connect to database. Message from SQL Server: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING "/" FROM domain.url), "/") `key`, CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING "/" FROM domain.url), "/") url, LOWER(HEX(domain.id)) id, LOWER(HEX(sales_channel.id)) salesChannelId, LOWER(HEX(sales_channel.type_id)) typeId, LOWER(HEX(domain.snippet_set_id)) snippetSetId, LOWER(HEX(domain.currency_id)) currencyId, LOWER(HEX(domain.language_id)) languageId, LOWER(HEX(theme.id)) themeId, sales_channel.maintenance maintenance, sales_channel.maintenance_ip_whitelist maintenanceIpWhitelist, snippet_set.iso as locale, theme.technical_name as themeName, parentTheme.technical_name as parentThemeName FROM sales_channel INNER JOIN sales_channel_domain domain ON domain.sales_channel_id = sales_channel.id LEFT JOIN theme_sales_channel theme_sales_channel ON sales_channel.id = theme_sales_channel.sales_channel_id INNER JOIN snippet_set snippet_set ON snippet_set.id = domain.snippet_set_id LEFT JOIN theme theme ON theme_sales_channel.theme_id = theme.id LEFT JOIN theme parentTheme ON theme.parent_theme_id = parentTheme.id WHERE (sales_channel.type_id = UNHEX(?)) AND (sales_channel.active)' with params ["8a243080f92e4c719546314b577cf82b"]: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '/' in 'field list'*

**Infos:**

- Shopware Version 6.2.3
- PHP 7.2
- MySQL 8.0.30
- Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64-bit
- Apache
- SQL Mode Settings (ANSI,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,STRICT_ALL_TABLES)

(Please ask if you need the version of something else) (The DNS of the Domain currently shows to the live-page. I adjusted my local system so that I go to the new Hosting when I type the URL of the live-page. For that I used the /System32/drivers/etc/hosts file. I can explain more detailed if necessary.)

**Shopware Logs (Last entries):**
[2023-12-19 13:17:09] request.INFO: Matched route "api.action.message-queue.consume". {"route":"api.action.message-queue.consume","route_parameters":{"_route":"api.action.message-queue.consume","_controller":"Shopware\Core\Framework\MessageQueue\Api\ConsumeMessagesController::consumeMessages","version":"2"},"request_uri":"http://91.92.117.219/api/v2/_action/message-queue/consume","method":"POST"} []
[2023-12-19 13:17:19] messenger.INFO: Received message Shopware\Core\Content\Category\DataAbstractionLayer\CategoryIndexingMessage {"message":"[object] (Shopware\Core\Content\Category\DataAbstractionLayer\CategoryIndexingMessage: {})","class":"Shopware\Core\Content\Category\DataAbstractionLayer\CategoryIndexingMessage"} []
[2023-12-19 13:17:19] request.INFO: Matched route "api.action.scheduled-task.run". {"route":"api.action.scheduled-task.run","route_parameters":{"_route":"api.action.scheduled-task.run","_controller":"Shopware\Core\Framework\MessageQueue\ScheduledTask\Api\ScheduledTaskController::runScheduledTasks","version":"2"},"request_uri":"http://91.92.117.219/api/v2/_action/scheduled-task/run","method":"POST"} []
[2023-12-19 13:17:28] request.INFO: Matched route "api.message_queue_stats.list". {"route":"api.message_queue_stats.list","route_parameters":{"_route":"api.message_queue_stats.list","_controller":"Shopware\Core\Framework\Api\Controller\ApiController::list","entityName":"message-queue-stats","version":"2","path":""},"request_uri":"http://91.92.117.219/api/v2/message-queue-stats?limit=25&page=1","method":"GET"} []
[2023-12-19 13:17:41] request.INFO: Matched route "api.action.message-queue.consume". {"route":"api.action.message-queue.consume","route_parameters":{"_route":"api.action.message-queue.consume","_controller":"Shopware\Core\Framework\MessageQueue\Api\ConsumeMessagesController::consumeMessages","version":"2"},"request_uri":"http://91.92.117.219/api/v2/_action/message-queue/consume","method":"POST"} []

**Apache Log (Last entries):**
[Tue Dec 19 13:05:11.716246 2023] [php7:error] [pid 397128] [client 93.220.248.166:50020] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/leitner-sales.at/vendor/shopware/core/Profiling/Doctrine/DebugStack.php on line 50
[Tue Dec 19 13:05:11.720171 2023] [php7:error] [pid 397128] [client 93.220.248.166:50020] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /var/www/leitner-sales.at/vendor/symfony/debug/DebugClassLoader.php on line 160
[Tue Dec 19 13:05:31.480669 2023] [php7:error] [pid 397275] [client 93.220.248.166:50050] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36864 bytes) in /var/www/leitner-sales.at/vendor/shopware/storefront/Framework/Cache/CacheTagCollection.php on line 27
[Tue Dec 19 13:05:31.490744 2023] [php7:error] [pid 397275] [client 93.220.248.166:50050] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /var/www/leitner-sales.at/vendor/symfony/debug/DebugClassLoader.php on line 160
[Tue Dec 19 13:05:56.795207 2023] [php7:error] [pid 397157] [client 93.220.248.166:50133] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/leitner-sales.at/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php on line 167
[Tue Dec 19 13:05:56.798689 2023] [php7:error] [pid 397157] [client 93.220.248.166:50133] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /var/www/leitner-sales.at/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/DataCollector/RequestDataCollector.php on line 139

**What I tried:**

- Adding and removing "/" in Sales Channels URLs
- Checked the Sales-Channels DB Tables
- Checked where the Code comes from (RequestTransformer.php = vendor->shopware->storefront->Framework->Routing)
- Clearing Caches
- Regenerate Indizes
- Restarted Server and Apache
- Checked the Logs
- DB access is correct and works
- DB Tables are present
- Apache Memory is at 512M
- I checked via Shell the Memory and more than half of it was free / unused.
- Checked permissions in Shopware folder
- Suggestions from other people in reports I found on stackoverflow and Shopware community (None of these worked or were relatable to my problem)
- Compiled Theme again

**What I´expecting:**
I need a functional Storefront that´s the same as the curent live so we can change the Domain DNS to the new Hosting.
Rigth now I need the 500 error/Shopware error to be fixed.

Comment: I don't know anything about Shopware but it's using a non-standard syntax for strings (`"/"` instead of `'/'`). That fails if your MySQL server (as it seems to be the case) has [ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) enabled.

Comment: I checked it and ANSI_QUOTES isn´t enabled.
Here my sql mode settings:
ANSI,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,STRICT_ALL_TABLES

Comment: Ah okay I had only "ANSI" in my sql_mode active. I deleted that. That solved the error. But sadly another error appeared. I´ll look into it now, but this error is solved at least.

Comment: [`key` is a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K) and needs to be quoted with backticks - ``CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM domain.url), '/') `key`,``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from "Álvaro González" helped.
"I don't know anything about Shopware but it's using a non-standard syntax for strings ("/" instead of '/'). That fails if your MySQL server (as it seems to be the case) has ANSI_QUOTES enabled."

I deleted the "ANSI," value from my sql_mode from my database and the error was gone.
Then I had another error but that one isn´t related to this post so I view this one as fixed.
I just needed to access the storefront with the storefront URL and everything works now.